# Proper format for date in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am trying to run this query and every time I try to fix it I get all sorts of different errors, I believe this to be the correct syntax but it keeps telling me I have an invalid date identifier. Ive looked online but can't quite find what I'm trying to do here.

```
SELECT CUST_FNAME, CUST_LNAME, CUST_STREET, CUST_CITY, CUST_STATE, CUST_ZIP
FROM LGCUSTOMER, LGPRODUCT, LGBRAND 
WHERE BRAND_NAME = 'FORESTERS BEST' 
AND INV_DATE BETWEEN '15-JUL-11' AND '31-JUL-11'
ORDER BY CUST_STATE, CUST_LNAME, CUST_FNAME;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that data type of the column `INV_DATE` is `DATE`. If so, you should provide `DATE` value to the `BETWEEN` condition.

You can check the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` parameter of your database. It specifies the default date format for `TO_CHAR` and `TO_DATE` function. IF the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` is `DD-MMM-YY` or `DD-MMM-RR`, your query should run ok. Otherwise, you should change the date string in your query to follow the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT`. Or you can use `TO_DATE` function like the following.

```
...
AND INV_DATE BETWEEN TO_DATE('15-JUL-11', 'DD-MMM-RR') AND TO_DATE('31-JUL-11', 'DD-MMM-RR')
...
```

Perhaps you should want to read what `NLS_DATE_FORMAT`, check [oracle documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28320/initparams137.htm#REFRN10119).

Comment: Still gives me the "INV_DATE" invalid identifier.

Comment: Well, In which table the column `INV_DATE` reside? If it is in table `X`, try to use `X.INV_DATE`, and see what happens?

Comment: Im getting closer, now its just running and wont stop.

Comment: I got it, i had a extra table in there that wasn't needed for my query. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 2):

In my version of Oracle I use `'15 Jul 11'` But this is setting dependent. To be certain you should use something like `TO_DATE('20110715','YYYYMMDD')` as it explicitly states the format.

Answer (score 0):

And besides, you should rarely use the date format 'MON', as it depends the language and environment as well.

For example, it will fail if you try to convert '26-NOV-13' to date using format DD-MON-RR in Chinese language environment. because the MON will be matched with "11月", not "NOV"

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the standard format for date literals:

```
SELECT CUST_FNAME, CUST_LNAME, CUST_STREET, CUST_CITY, CUST_STATE, CUST_ZIP
FROM LGCUSTOMER, LGPRODUCT, LGBRAND 
WHERE BRAND_NAME = 'FORESTERS BEST' 
AND INV_DATE BETWEEN DATE '2011-07-15' AND DATE '2011-07-31'
ORDER BY CUST_STATE, CUST_LNAME, CUST_FNAME;
```